# mysqli not found in (php-fpm) docker container

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, fpm

I'm running [php:7-fpm](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/fa6464a43d74d8b0a5ec3f22d53ac330f63ad22d/7.1/fpm/Dockerfile) in a docker container that is used by my nginx web server. Everything is working nicely except for when I'm trying to instantiate a mysqli connection in my PHP code. I receive the following error:

```
"NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Listener\mysqli' not found in index.php:104
```

Here's my Dockerfile for building the image, where I explicitly install the mysqli extension:

```
FROM php:7-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

It appears to be installed given the phpinfo() output below. Do I need to configure or enable it somehow?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem isn't that you're missing the mysqli extension.

If you're doing something like this:

```
namespace Listener;

class Foo
{
    public function bar() {
        $conn = new mysqli(...);
    }
}
```

Then PHP will interpret `new mysqli()` as `new \Listener\mysqli()` because you're currently in the `\Listener` namespace. To fix this, you can just explicitly anchor `mysqli()` to the root namespace:

```
$conn = new \mysqli(...);
```